# How to install a specific version of Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am trying to install Symfony 4.0 (specifically 4.0.99) to prepare for Symfony SF4 certification but each time composer installs 4.4.11 instead.

I tried:

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton="4.0.99" skeleton
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton="4.0.*" skeleton
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton="~4.0.99" skeleton
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton skeleton "4.0.99"
```

Even if all packages in vendor folder are listed with 4.0.9 versions, the main page of the application fails to open because of different errors:

```
In ArrayNode.php line 327:
Unrecognized option "cookie_samesite" under "framework.session". Available
options are "cookie_domain", "cookie_httponly", "cookie_lifetime",
"cookie_path", "cookie_secure", "enabled", "gc_divisor", "gc_maxlifetime",
"gc_probability", "handler_id", "metadata_update_threshold", "name",
"save_path", "storage_id", "use_cookies".
```

I tried using raw [composer.json](https://github.com/symfony/website-skeleton/blob/4.0/composer.json) for 4.0 branch and then stricly modified each dependency to "4.0.9".

I tried using PHP 7.0 instead of PHP 7.1 and use --ignore-platform-reqs

Is something wrong with my OS? Can you get fresh **working** installation of Symfony 4.0?

Comment: Here this url already has the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749655/how-do-i-create-a-project-based-on-a-specific-version-of-symfony-using-composer . Try it by your self .

Comment: There is no version 4.0.99 of Symfony, the latest version of Symfony 4.0 is 4.0.15

Comment: @NicoHaase thx, versioning is kind of confusing within what I see in tags in repo and what I see as I use composer create-project

Comment: @kaviranga that's not the answer simply because using ^ in front of the package version will give you last stable version with this number, e.g ^4.4 = 4.4 and ^4.0 = 4.4. I need 4.0 precisely.

Comment: The answer was to use specific restrictions in composer.json - https://pastebin.com/AZJKRKSD

Comment: @AlbertoGuerra Please, write a real answer for this question with this code and more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Via `composer`, what the Symfony [documentation](http://The%20lts%20and%20next%20shortcuts%20are%20only%20available%20when%20using%20Symfony%20to%20create%20new%20projects.%20If%20you%20use%20Composer,%20you%20need%20to%20tell%20the%20exact%20version:%20%20%20composer%20create-project%20symfony/website-skeleton:%5E4.4%20my_project_name) says:

```
 composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton:^4.4 my_project_name
```

You can also do like this:

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my_project_name 4.4
```

You should not use quote for the version in the `composer` command. So, your command will be like (it works with me):

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton:4.0.99 skeleton
```

About requirements for [Symfony 4.0](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/setup.html):

> To create your new Symfony application, first make sure you’re using PHP 7.1 or higher and have Composer installed.

If you still want to use PHP 7.0 for your app, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35273522/how-to-always-use-ignore-platform-reqs-flag-when-running-composer) or use `--ignore-platform-reqs` to ignore php and ext requirements as you did.

Comment: I don't need 4.4 version and I already tried these commands.

Comment: 4.4 was an example. For your case, use the third command line in the anwser.